# Dex2jar issue: the src file is not a .dex file

Tags: android, dex, dex2jar

I have a dex file I want to convert to a .jar file; it's 4.5MB, it starts with qh(null), its called classes.dex and I think it's valid.

In my windows machine, when running dex2jar.bat on it I get an error:

```
java.io.IOException: the src file not a .dex or zip file
```

What kind of an issue could cause this? How could I validate the .dex file, or parse it properly?

Comment: If the tool is telling you it's not a valid dex file, why do you believe it's a valid dex file?

Comment: It is unpacked and run dynamically on an application, and I think it works properly. Either way I'd like to understand it better.